# How to build a timer/delay relay

Tags: relay, dc, timer

I want to build timer or delay relay, so that after I remove 12V DC from it, it keeps pulling for 1 second, and then releases.

What are the components that I need to add to a 12VDC relay?

Comment: Can you keep the 12v and remove a trigger?

Comment: Yes, it's an option.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store at least 1 second of relay-coil-drive current.

1 farad charged to 15 volts, providing 1 amp current, will sag to 14 volts in one second, to 12 volts in 3 seconds. There are better ways.

Comment: The voltage source for the coil is in the shape of pulses, can it charge a 1f cap?