# Delay relay triggered by switch turning off

Tags: switches, relay, delay

I've got a dilemma. I'm trying to set up a delay relay for a boat shower waste pump.

The waste pump is triggered by some microswitches when water flows to the shower. I want the pump to continue to run once the switch has been disengaged (shower turned off).

At the moment, my relay setup activates when trigger switch is turned on but disengaged after x seconds (potentially whilst still in the shower!). I want it to continue to activate whilst the trigger switch is on and delay once trigger switch has been turned off. What should I be looking for?

Ps.I can't find the answer to my question in the forum

Comment: Search for "monostable" or "one-shot" circuits. It is hard for me to believe that a reasonable search didn't turn up something relevant...this gets asked about every other day.

Comment: Thank you Elliot I'll have a look - sarky comment - less appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to wire up a timer module from ebay, or build a small circuit from scratch?  What are the power sources for timer device and the pump?  What is your "relay setup" now?  This might be as simple as wiring it differently.

Comment: So it's 12v and at the moment I've got a 12v delay relay with three six connection points - three on each side - it works well as an initial trigger to get the pump working, but it stops after say, 60s. If I'm having a shower longer than that time and the flow switch is still on, I'd need to turn the shower off then on again to reactivate the pump. From my research I think need a combination of NOTO and NOTC. Excuse my lack of knowledge I'm pretty new to electrics and was never particularly good at it at school!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build a timer/delay relay](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/491482/how-to-build-a-timer-delay-relay)

Comment: Hi so unfortunately not - I want to know what ready made circuit board to purchase as I'm not really in a position to be building circuits from scratch (no PCB facility etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one example.

[image: Pump Run-On Timer]

On power-up R6 & C3 ensure relay is switched off.

Sensor switch closes, relay energises and timer is held in reset.

At end of shower sensor switch opens, timer is enabled and starts to run.

At end of timing period, timer output goes high and relay is switched off.

Timer can be reset even when it's running by sensor switch closing.

Timing period is set by combination of the values of C2, R4, VR1 and also which of the outputs of the 4060 is selected.

I haven't selected the timing component values or output for any particular timing period. They would need to be calculated.

**EDIT**

Hi Damian,

This afternoon I have built and tested the above circuit and found it to work very well.

I have measured the run-on delays for three different IC2 outputs, with the timing components shown (VR1, C2, R4). The results are as follows.

IC2, pin 13 : 3s to 30s

IC2, pin 15 : 6s to 60s

IC2, pin 1 : 24s to 240s

**EDIT**

Added supply filtering.

[image: Pump Run-On Timer]

Comment: That's great! I'll have a look at implementing it. Really appreciate your help James

Comment: @ Damian Jffrs See edit with timing info.

Comment: Thank you James!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a 12V DC 'Adjustable Time Relay with switch off delay'.

Comment: This!!! Awesome, I think this solves it completely. Much appreciated.

Comment: Anytime, Damian!

Answer (score -1):

Build it? Sure, you could, using a small micro with a relay, or use a counter.

Or you could buy it. Maybe this: https://www.alliedelec.com/product/rs-pro-by-allied/8700720/70658603

Or this: [https://www.amazon.com/Delay-Relay-Board-Switch-Module/dp/B00VFUG3KK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00VFUG3KK)

Comment: Marker-debbie-downer: A reminder that Engineering is about problem-solving, and that make-vs. buy is *always* a legitimate engineering choice (copy-concept being another.)